# Hibernate MySQL native LOCK TABLES query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, locking, micronaut

When I execute LOCK TABLES query as a native query in hibernate and try to access the locked table, I am getting an error `Table 'orgaccount0_' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`. I think it due to the alias name used by hibernate. The actual table name is org_account.JPA entity name for the table is OrgAccount.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

```java
public Optional<OrgAccount> findTop1ByStatus(OrgAccountStatusName name) {
        this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("LOCK TABLES org_account WRITE").executeUpdate();
        List<OrgAccount> orgAccounts = entityManager
                .createQuery("FROM OrgAccount AS oa WHERE oa.status = :status", OrgAccount.class)
                .setParameter("status", name).getResultList();
        ...
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }
```

Comment: or simply 'org_account' != 'OrgAccount'

Comment: Btw there's very few uses for 'LOCK TABLES', you are probably after transactions. What do you wish to acheive?

Comment: Check the name of your table name in your entity class OrgAccount

Comment: Hi, @danblack. I have a rest api endpoint that has to read data from the table exclusively, preventing read/write on the table until the function finishes.